# select * from [table] where min(date) > certain date

Tags: sql, date, aggregate, min

i have a table with customers. every customers has several orders with the paid price and day he/she ordered an item. i want only customers their first order was after a certain date

orders table looks like this:

```
id | customer | item | price | date
--------------------------------------------
1  |    a      |  a2  |   50  | 2018-07-03 
2  |    b      |  a5  |   30  | 2019-12-06
3  |    c      |  a3  |   20  | 2020-01-14
4  |    a      |  a2  |   23  | 2017-07-12
5  |    f      |  a1  |   34  | 2018-10-03
6  |    c      |  a1  |   90  | 2018-03-03
7  |    b      |  a2  |   56  | 2020-02-03
8  |    a      |  a2  |   52  | 2019-05-03

SELECT customer FROM orders WHERE min(date) > TO_DATE('2018-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

i want the customer only when the first order was after 2018-09-01, the min(date) > TO_DATE('2018-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')

result should be customers:
b
f

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT customer
FROM orders o
GROUP BY customer
HAVING min(date) > DATE '2018-09-01';
```

You don't need to convert the date to a string for comparisons.  Depending on your database, `DATE` may not be required.

Comment: I think `DATE` should not be in there?

Comment: Since fabvy didn't explicitly state which RDBMS is being used, Gordon may be assuming that the RDBMS is Oracle based on content in fabvy's post.  Yes DATE is needed.  Otherwise you're comparing strings.  Of course, fabvy also didn't state what the data type of the date column is, so who knows.  Overall, poorly-worded question.

Comment: @dougp . . . `date` is actually standard SQL for introducing a date literal.  Not all databases support it.